# Mongoose promise error due to Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I got below error from my error log. I don't know when it occurs, unable to track the issue as it not shows my code instead it shows node_module(mongoose). It would be great if you send your thoughts to debug and fix.

As I googled, I came to know that it happens when recursive call of Async function. But I am not doing any recursive call or looping through Async call.

Thanks,
Thavaprakash. S.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Promise.emit (/home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1544:35)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Promise.emit (/home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    at handleSave (/home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:133:13)
    at /home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:408:16
    at /home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:128:9
    at /home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1195:7
    at /home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:453:41)
    at /home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:487:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:445:20)
```

update:

Please find the below sample code.

```
   var Promise = require('bluebird');
   var Business = require('business.model');
   var User = require('user.model');
   var userPromise = User.findOne({userId:121454}, function (err, user) {}).exec();
   Promise.all([userPromise]).then(function(results){ // here one promise passed, we may pass multiple promise in future
         var user = results[0];
         Business.findOne({bid:user.businessId},{}, function (err, busin) {
           if(err){
                  console.log(err);
                  res.status(500); 
                  return res.json({"code":500,"error": "internal server error"}) 
           } 

           res.status(200);
           return res.json({"name": busin.name}) 

         });
   });
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: first you show drill down to the model which is erring out, for that put some console.logs to get the model name in `/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js`
You can share the code that is buggy after you have found it out, until then no one would be able to help you out

Comment: Thanks Hiren and Vineet, let me drill down and share my code.

Comment: I shared my sample code. Please go through and let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

I have received answer from below link. Thanks to VKarpov

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3582#issuecomment-158436688

Thanks, Thavaprakash. S.